# I cannot deploy the file which I unzipped

Tags: android, node.js, mobile, cordova

I tried to deploy the file/application which I unzipped on android, but it didn't work.

**Here is the error message.**

```
Error: /Users/kinoshitaryou/niamee/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Someone, please help me!!!!